# How can I specify the jpos.xml path for JavaPos

Tags: java, configuration, javapos

I want to load my `jops.xml` which includes my JavaPos decives from a custom location. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to easily load a XML-based Config File into a Java Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501325/how-to-easily-load-a-xml-based-config-file-into-a-java-class)

Comment: The magic happens with the jpos populator file prop name constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it with the `JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME` property.

Example how to set it to an env-var:

```
System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, System.getenv("jposxml_path"));
```

Comment: is it possible to load it with "getResourceAsStream", b/c I want to load it from inside a jar

Comment: don't know, you can somehow load a jpos file manually. Check the jpostest2 (https://github.com/ntsggr/JavaPOS-POStest-2) tool, maybe you find something in its sourcecode.